# FireFox doesn't display any warning dialog for window beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, firefox

Currently working the latest version of Firefox desktop browser. Trying to capture the window beforeunload event. Below code works for IE, Chrome and Safari but not with Firefox.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "Test Test";
  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
  return confirmationMessage;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Firefox's documentation:

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with.

You cannot show pop-up if user didn't interacted with the page before. Also, it is better to use the following code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```

Comment: The issue was I was closing  Firefox browser without any interaction.