# Firefox onbeforeunload handler and window focus

Tags: javascript, firefox, onbeforeunload

**Solved in** [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

**Original question**

I'm curently using Firefox ESR 45.3.0, and I've written a small test page:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "foo"};
        </script>
        <p>content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**erroneous behavior:**

1. load any page
2. load this test page (can also be reproduced via "file:///...")
3. click browser back
4. the confirm dialog **is not shown**

**correct behavior:**

5. load any page
6. load this test page
7. click inside the window
8. click browser back
9. the confirm dialog **is shown**

I've also played around with the console (developer tools), trying to set focus on window or body, still not working without clicking the page.
My original problem page is longer, instead of 7. you can also scroll the page by mousewheel, this also "activates" the onbeforeunload handler.

Strange, looks like a Firefox bug, do you have any hints how to deal with this problem?

Regards,
Gunnar

**Update 1**

Working with e.returnValue does not fix the problem, I've tested it in the test page shown above.

The test page is very simple, my original javascript code in the original problem page is copied from some other question/answer and goes like

```
function checkModelChanged(modelChanged, confirmText)
{
    if (modelChanged === true)
    {
        var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
        var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

        myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
            (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmText;
            return confirmText;
        });        
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

1. The test page works as expected in Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m and Edge 38.14393.0.0 (EdgeHTML 14.14393). Browser back without "window interaction" shows the confirm dialog.
2. The original problem page is part of a Liferay Portlet (JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 5.3), and I've already tried javascript's scollIntoView and jQuery's animate (scrollTop) or trigger (click).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

Comment: no it isn't a duplicate of `is it possible to display a custom message` - because it's not a custom message that the question is asking for

Comment: `Update 2 point 1` - firefox **requires** interaction before this event will fire - which makes sense, without interaction, there can be no data to lose

Comment: @JaromandaX, this is a duplicated because it says exactly which browsers **accept** a custom message and which don't, and also regarding update #2 - It also there in the answer of the duplicated question.

Comment: @Dekel - I shoulda clicked da link shouldn't I :p

Comment: @JaromandaX, what?

Comment: @Dekel - you're right, it is a duplicate - I was posting "dumb" version of "I should have clicked the link of the duplicate rather than just read the question in th elink text, then I would've seen that all the information was right there" :p

Comment: @JaromandaX oh :) well, you are welcome to upvote my answer there ;)

Comment: well, no wonder you knew about it :p

Comment: @JaromandaX, it took some time to validate and check all browsers and stuff...

Comment: Thanks Dekel, upvoted your answer over there.

Comment: Sure :) you are welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: The problem is not only with the "back" button. It also appears when you try to close the tab and you didn't interacted withe the page first. FF62. I think the problem is for every trigger of "onbeforeunload". @JaromandaX "firefox requires interaction before this event will fire - which makes sense" - what about if you are loading many initialisation data in an offline-capable web-app and you want to avoid an unintended tab-close, in order not to lose this data or the static content? I thin it would make sense to see the dialog without having interacted with the page.

Comment: The question is not how to fix a FF-bug wich is no bug. The question is how to programmatically do possible in javascript, that "beforeunload" triggers without initially user interaction. About the sense, I explained above. With this title, this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @user3408530 - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup