# Javascript/Html Close Window Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do this in html and js but not refresh or reload just trigger when its getting closed. I used functions like onbeforeunload,unload but they didnt work.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETBlo.gif)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

Answer (score 1):

Try This with jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

Or with javascript

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```