# Notify user to save changes in Javascript or jQuery if page is not getting refresh before rendering other partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I am working with asp.net MVC project. I do have partial views and rendering those view via AJAX call only, so I am not performing whole page refresh.

In one partial view user is making changes and calling another partial view without saving it.

So I want to force user with an alert to save changes before leaving edited partial view.

Is that possible using Javascript, jQuery or any other way?

I tried:

```
 window.onload = function () {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
            alert("was checked out, please check in back.");});
};
```

but its working on whole page refresh only.
I am not refreshing whole page only partial page using AJAX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

Comment: Nope, beforeunload only fires when whole html page refreshed.

Comment: @RaviAnand : I know I may be a bit late, but did you find a solution to your problem ? I am facing the same problem in Angular JS application.