# How to display a pop up, when a user tries to leave the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a conformation pop up, when user tries to leave the page (close the tab) asking him/her "You want to leave the page? Yes No". When the user click the NO, I want to redirect him/her to a specific URL.
Here is the code I have tried:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){

   $.Zebra_Dialog('Are you sure to leave the page?', {
      'type':     'question',
       'title':    'Conformation',
       'buttons':  ['Yes', 'No'],
   });
   $("html").on("click",".ZebraDialog_Button_0",function () {
       window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
   });
   $("html").on("click",".ZebraDialog_Button_1",function () {
       return true;
   });
   //return false;
});
```

Comment: There's an `onExit` handler, or something similar.  I don't see anything in your code that attempts to catch a user as they leave.

Comment: Already attached beforeunload event.

Comment: whoops, my bad :/. And what does the above code end up doing?

Comment: When you want to show popup when user leaves(navigate to other site) a page or when user tries to close the page

Comment: When user tries to close the tab/page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

Answer (score 3):

```
    window.onbeforeunload = onExit;
    function onExit() {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
```

Try this, i have tested firefox and chrome its working not idea about safari.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I redirect the user to a specific URL when he/she click the "Stay button" on the confirmation box?

Basically I want a custom conformation box/ pop up, when user close the page asking him "You want to leave the page? ".with yes/no buttons. When user clicks the yes button the tab will be closed and when user clicks the No button, he will be redirected to a specific URL(e.g www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#reload').click(function() {
        location.reload();
    });
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        return 'Are you sure to leave the page?';
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I redirect the user to a specific URL when he/she click the "Stay button" on the confirmation box? Basically I want a custom conformation box/ pop up, when user close the page asking him "You want to leave the page? ".with yes/no buttons. When user clicks the yes button the tab will be closed and when user clicks the No button, he will be redirected to a specific URL(e.g www.google.com)