# Override onbeforeunload popup with my custom popup

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Is there any way that i can override onbeforeunload popup ?

I tried with below but it does't work:

```
if($('body').hasClass('admin')){
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        notifySaveChangesUser(event);   
        //return null;
        //event.returnValue = "Say";
    };
}

function notifySaveChangesUser(event){
    //Doing some stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup).

TL;DR: You can customize message by returning the desired string from the handler:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "You have some unsaved changes";
};
```

See the answer above for more details and browser quirks.

Comment: I don't want to default popup. I am using apprise popup. I need to show that instead of default popup. Please let me know if you have any idea ?

Comment: Well, as far as I know, the support for custom popups has been removed in recent versions of all modern browsers. I think it is ok to use the default one, as many big players, like GitHub or Google use it and are doing fine.