# Custom message in onbeforeunload function

Tags: javascript

I want to add my custom message in the `onbeforeunload` function

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {                
    if(changes){  
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave without saving changes?'; 
    }               
}
```

But its showing default message, is there any possibility to overwrite it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup) | Looks like every browser removed support for custom message.