# JavaScript action before leaving the page without beforeonload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a confirmation before user leaving the page. If he says ok then it would redirect to new page or cancel to leave. I tried to make it with onunload .

I tried beforeunload, It is working OK.
But I can't put confirm/alert inside beforeunload .

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
    if (flag_change_index == true) {
        var msg = 'You are about to leave the page.  Continue?';
        return msg;  //Webkit
    }
});
```

[Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

So, I need to 1 solution instead of beforeunload. It would be even better if someone shows how to do it with jQuery?
Thank you.

Comment: _I can't put confirm/alert inside beforeunload_, yes you can't

Comment: This really is a duplicate of the question you linked. I moved [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50132210/157247) there.

Comment: Yes , I know duplicate . But I need to 1 solution instead of beforeunload.