# How to display component using react-router <Prompt> to prevent or allow route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm currently trying to find a way to display a custom component (like a Modal) to confirm route changes using the `Prompt` component.

The default behavior of the `Promp` component is to show a confirm dialog with a message, as you can see in this [Example: React Router: Preventing Transitions.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions)

Note: I am using the `<BrowserRouter>` component.

The router has a `prop` named `getUserConfirmation`, which you can use to customize the behavior of the `<Prompt>` component.

```
// this is the default behavior

function getConfirmation(message, callback) {
  const allowTransition = window.confirm(message);
  callback(allowTransition);
}

<BrowserRouter getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation} />;
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Inside the parent component APP

  - I'm setting the `confirm` state to true, to display the `<Confirm>` component
  - And I'm trying to pass the `callback` from the `getConfirmation` function to the `<Confirm>` component to call it with `true` to allow transition, and with `false` to prevent it.
  - The callback would be called with `true or false` in the default behavior as you can see above.

```
function getConfirmation(message, callback) {
    console.log("Inside getConfirmation function...");
    setConfirmCallback(callback);
    setConfirm(true);
    // const allowTransition = window.confirm(message);
    // callback(allowTransition);
  }
```

This is what **App.js** is rendering:

```
return (
    <Router getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation}>
      <AllRoutes />
      {confirm && (
        <Confirm confirmCallback={confirmCallback} setConfirm={setConfirm} />
      )}
    </Router>
  );
```

**What seems to be the problem:**

- The `confirm` dialog seems to block the function at that point. So the `callback` variable/parameter is still in scope. So everything works OK.
- When I remove the `confirm` dialog, that function runs all the way. And when I click on the confirm button inside the `<Confirm>` component, the `callback` no longer exists.

**QUESTION**

Does anybody know a way to achieve this behavior (preventing route changes using a custom component instead of a confirm dialog) using `react-router-dom`?

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactrouteranswerso-r12og)

Full code from CodeSandbox:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
  Prompt
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  console.log("Rendering App...");

  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);
  const [confirmCallback, setConfirmCallback] = useState(null);

  function getConfirmation(message, callback) {
    console.log("Inside getConfirmation function...");
    setConfirmCallback(callback);
    setConfirm(true);
    // const allowTransition = window.confirm(message);
    // callback(allowTransition);
  }

  return (
    <Router getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation}>
      <AllRoutes />
      {confirm && (
        <Confirm confirmCallback={confirmCallback} setConfirm={setConfirm} />
      )}
    </Router>
  );
}

function Confirm(props) {
  function allowTransition() {
    props.setConfirm(false);
    props.confirmCallback(true);
  }

  function blockTransition() {
    props.setConfirm(false);
    props.confirmCallback(false);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Are you sure?</div>
      <button onClick={allowTransition}>Yes</button>
      <button onClick={blockTransition}>No way</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function AllRoutes(props) {
  console.log("Rendering AllRoutes...");
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/comp1" component={Component1} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

function Home(props) {
  console.log("Rendering Home...");
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>This is Home</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/comp1">Component1</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component1(props) {
  console.log("Rendering Component1...");

  const [isBlocking, setIsBlocking] = useState(true);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Prompt
        when={isBlocking}
        message={location =>
          `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
        }
      />
      <div>This is component 1</div>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This post might help you: [ReactRouter v4 Prompt - override default alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437195/reactrouter-v4-prompt-override-default-alert/52437325#52437325)

Comment: That did help! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider upvoting such posts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by this [discussion](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4635) and by this [example](https://codepen.io/pshrmn/pen/MpOpEY?editors=0010), I was able to make my example working.

The problem was that when the `<Confirm>` was being created, the `setConfirmCallback()` call wasn't done yet. So the `<Confirm>` component wasn't able to use the `callback` from `getUserConfirmation`.

So I've changed this line:

```
FROM:
  setConfirmCallback(callback);
TO:
  setConfirmCallback(()=>callback);
```

And now it works!

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactrouteranswerso-r12og)

Full CodeSandbox code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
  Prompt
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  console.log("Rendering App...");

  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);
  const [confirmCallback, setConfirmCallback] = useState(null);

  function getConfirmation(message, callback) {
    console.log("Inside getConfirmation function...");
    setConfirmCallback(() => callback);
    setConfirm(true);
    // const allowTransition = window.confirm(message);
    // callback(allowTransition);
  }

  return (
    <Router getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation}>
      <AllRoutes />
      {confirm && (
        <Confirm confirmCallback={confirmCallback} setConfirm={setConfirm} />
      )}
    </Router>
  );
}

function Confirm(props) {
  console.log("Rendering Confirm...");
  function allowTransition() {
    props.setConfirm(false);
    props.confirmCallback(true);
  }

  function blockTransition() {
    props.setConfirm(false);
    props.confirmCallback(false);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Are you sure?</div>
      <button onClick={allowTransition}>Yes</button>
      <button onClick={blockTransition}>No way</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function AllRoutes(props) {
  console.log("Rendering AllRoutes...");
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/comp1" component={Component1} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

function Home(props) {
  console.log("Rendering Home...");
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>This is Home</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/comp1">Component1</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component1(props) {
  console.log("Rendering Component1...");

  const [isBlocking, setIsBlocking] = useState(true);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Prompt
        when={isBlocking}
        message={location =>
          `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
        }
      />
      <div>This is component 1</div>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Is it possible with StaticRouter? I am trying to do something similar with RactSSR.
How do I do it?

Comment: This was exactly what I needed :) Thank you @cbdeveloper

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple workaround for my case. I could not share the whole component but snippets.

```
// this will initiate the dialogbox render and 
// prevent the window from going back by returning false
const backButtonPressed = async () => {
    leavePrompt(false);
    return false;
}

// this will open the prompt dialog box
const leavePrompt = (endRoom) => {
    setOpenPrompt({open: true, action: endRoom ? "endRoom" : "leaveQuitely"});
}

// render
<Dialog open={openPrompt.open} aria-labelledby="interim-user-dialog-title">
    <DialogContent dividers>
        <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
            Are you sure?
        </Typography>
    </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={() => setOpenPrompt({...openPrompt, open: false})} color="primary">
                Stay
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => history.push("/")} color="secondary">
                Leave
            </Button>
        </DialogActions>
</Dialog>


// when allowedToGoBack state is true then call a method that will render the dialog box
<Prompt
    when={true}
    title={"Alert"}
    message={() => allowedToGoBack ? backButtonPressed() && false : true} 
/>
```