# Show a popup modal on page exit using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Does anyone know if it's possible to show a popup model on page exit(close tab/refresh/go back) with images and text using Javascript/jQuery?

The closest thing I found was **beforeunload** but it seems to only show an alert prompt with a predefined message.

Comment: It's possible, but the user won't see it because the window is closed...

Comment: Look for exit intent scripts, they fire upon the mouse leaving the `document`

Comment: That might be a good workaround but that will only detect when the mouse leaves the viewport not when the document is about to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think modern browsers support a custom message in the `beforeunload` modal popup. [Check this post for a discussion on browser compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

Comment: Yes, it shows a predefined message by the browser, so I can't use that.