# Does $(document).unload(function() {}); work when an iframe is redirecting the top level page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe on my site.
I do not own the website in the iframe and can't edit the code.

When a user clicks a link inside the iframe the iframe redirects the top level url.

I want to detect when the page is about to be redirected and display a notice saying they are about to be redirected. I have tried using unload.function but it does not get triggered.

```
$(document).unload(function()
{
    alert(1);
});
```

Is it possible to execute js after the user has clicked the link in the iframe before the page is redirected?

Thanks

Comment: What you do is to put a div over the iframe and capture the events that way.  When the user is ready to move one, simply move the div or erase it completely.

Answer (score 1):

In the top level frame - i.e your code attach a  `beforeunload` event to the `window` and then something like this...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
};
```

This answer goes into detail about who will actually see your custom message - [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup) - Most browsers ignore the string even though its in the spec

Comment: It’s true that the code for a `beforeunload` prompt is “something like that”, but it’s not that. :P