# Remove beforeunload alert() and show custom popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hello, I am working on nextJs project, there is a unique requirement when the user goes to close the browser tab that time needs to open some other popup, but there is one problem when I click on to tab close button first default shows me this alert then I click to cancel then its show my popup, the requirement is open only my popup(i don't want change alert box message, just need to off alert box.), please help me if anyone knows solution Thank you.

> My Popup is not an alert box, its an HTML and CSS.

[image]

```
  const [openPopUp, setOpenPopUp] = useState(false);

  const onBackButtonEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setOpenPopUp(true)
    e.returnValue = "";
    return ""
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onBackButtonEvent);
    window.alert = function() { }; 
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onBackButtonEvent);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup) Impossible to do

Comment: @Konrad my custom popup is not an alert box, its an HTML and CSS.

Comment: It's even worse. You still can't do that

Comment: You can not replace the beforeunload pop up. So your task is not possible.

Comment: You can't "do" anything in the `beforeunload` event. It can only be used to trigger the browser-dialog for confirming or cancelling the page unload, through a call to `evt.preventDefault()`.

Comment: (And of course, using this event stops the page from being added to the back/forward cache, so it makes history navigation quite a lot slower. You basically don't want to use this event at all. In a React app, just assume users will close tabs, and let them because you're constantly saving or syncing anything that needs saving or syncing)