'Leave site?' Alert Isn't Triggered When Chrome Beta is Launched Using ChromeDriver
I'm running tests on Chrome Beta and it looks like the alert functionality has stopped working. If the steps that trigger the alert are performed in a manually opened Chrome Beta browser, the alert appears as expected. However, performing the same actions (even manually) in a browser opened by ChromeDriver does not trigger the alert.
I've created an issue for ChromeDriver, but meanwhile, I'm trying to find a workaround for this.
Is it possible to add some driver options or do anything else to make these alerts work in tests?

have you set unExpectedAlertBehaviour?  I believe default is dismiss and notify (notify is an exception).

@browsermator I've tried to put it in ignore but it doesn't help.
I actually discovered that alerts are working with Chrome Beta 127 + Chrome Driver 126. And not working with Chrome Beta 127 and Chrome driver 127

according to that W3C spec the onBeforeUnload handler is special.  It will default to Accept... which presumably goes ahead with the action to close the tab/window. (it may appear and be accepted so fast you won't see it)  You might show the code you are using to set unExpectedAlertBehaviour, as there are specific constants you need to use there.

It should be something like: options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(promptBehaviorConstant); in Java.

@browsermator i tried to use in like this options.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Ignore;
It is the only way which Selenium let's me. I'm using c#. I saw "setUnhandledPromptBehaviour" but i assume it is working for Java only

@browsermator i also found such bug. https://issues.chromium.org/issues/42323841
it is possible that it is connected with my issue but i'm not sure

Be sure to use "Behaviour" (british spelling for some reason)  Also see this thread about onbeforeunload behavior in modern browsers.  It looks like the browsers switched over to a set browser prompt.  (not an alert): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup  Seems like that should still throw unexpectedalert on .quit() if the behaviour option is set.
