How to display beforeunload as alert box instead of a warning to leave page
I am trying to stop users from moving onto next page unless they click on a checkbox. I have used beforeunload to trigger the "do you want to leave the site". However, I would rather get rid of the option to leave the site and just have it as some sort of alert popup, telling users they cannot proceed unless they click the checkbox.
I cannot access the < a > tag or do anything with it. It is hard-coded to go to another page, and cannot seem to figure out how to stop the redirect and display an alert box on check of the checkbox.
<form>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Check1" id="Check1" value="Check1" value="yes" required>
  this is the first checkbox</label>

  <button>continue</button>
</form>

<a href="https://example.com">outer link</a>

Here is the javascript for accessing eventUnload:
function isChecked() {
  return document.getElementById("Check1").checked
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(ev) {
  if (!isChecked()) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.returnValue = '';
  }
})


This is no longer possible. All that can be shown to the user in beforeunload is the modal box confirming their intention to leave. It used to be possible to customise the message, or perform other tasks as you're trying to do here, but it was massively abused and so modern browsers do not allow those behaviours. More information on the current behaviour, and example of how to implement it, is available at MDN

See this specific answer in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68637899/519413

Is there any way to trigger a popup that stops the user from being redirected without interacting with the < a > tag?

If you want a "continue" button that checks before proceeding, it will be a different solution from eg the user just navigating to a different site by entering a new url.

@fdomn-m thank you. Could you point me in the right direction of how to make a "continue" button without touching the < a > tag?

The link in the comment above is a general-purpose handler:
