# How to disable F5 or refresh button of an application developed using angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

the application is developed using routing concepts of angular2 and when I run npm start and after loading successfully and application open up in a browser, after opening the F5 and refresh button in a browser should be disabled.

Comment: Not possible, as it should be. Why would you want that ?

Comment: Please explain the full problem, since you can't disable `F5` or the browser buttons.

Comment: we already given a refresh button in the menu to refresh data,  because of this reason we need to disable F5 or refresh button in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

[While there probably are possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711815/can-i-disable-browser-refresh-in-my-webapp) to prevent a user refreshing or navigating from a page, I would strongly advise against using these kind of patterns.

Instead, try to preserve the users data if necessary (cookies, local storage, backend, ...).

Comment: F5 disable is working by adding the script in HTML, but still when is press refresh button on browser the page is loading, it should also be disabled.