# How to disable browser reload button on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable browser reload/refresh button on mouse click
I restrict f5 key so now page didn"t refesh or reload, but still user can page reload on mouse click on browser reload icon.

So, I want to disable or stop working browser reload button. 
I dont want to confirmation message or  warning message on reload button click.

Please help me if anybody have any suggestion.

Comment: Thankfully, that is not possible

Comment: invoke window.open("pagename","_self");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I disable browser refresh in my webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711815/can-i-disable-browser-refresh-in-my-webapp)

Comment: hi Liam,  I followed given link but there is no any option to disable browser reload button, they suggest to add confirm message like you want to reload or not?

Comment: @SatishGidhad The link provided was for a question which was the same as your but just worded differently - thus any solutions given for that question apply to your situation as well

Comment: Thanks to all for support

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (more likely fortunately) you cannot disable the refresh button on a page.

What you can do instead is you can warn the user not to refresh your page and inform them of the consequences of doing so. This is common practice as seen on multiple web pages which process online payments.