# How to prevent refresh of a browser window when a request is already been posted but the response is yet to come?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, page-refresh, post-redirect-get

Let say I have a HTML form and a submit button. When I click the submit button I submit a post request to the server for processing.

How do I prevent a refresh of the page while the request is been processed by the server. Please note that the server has not returned any response yet and the spinner is still spinning in the browser. This is the time where I want to disable refresh as the current request is still in process.

I have implemented POST/REDIRECT/GET , but the issue is that even before the server redirects , and if the request is still in process , then I want to disable the refresh till the server redirects the request.

Comment: Maybe you find here a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711815/can-i-disable-browser-refresh-in-my-webapp

Comment: Afaik there's nothing you can do to prevent this user action 100%. The browser should display a dialog box asking the user if they really want to submit the form data again, and if they confirm, the browser will send the entire POST request a second time. The only way to prevent this is passively, on the backend.

Comment: Why not an ajax request with javascript redirect?

Answer (score 0):

you need to event.preventDefault() to prevent refresh of page

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return ValidationEvent()">
...
...
<script>
function ValidationEvent(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //prevent refresh of page

// your ajax api call here
}
</script>
```

Comment: But the form is not submitted at all, and the handling of the inline event is off (the event object is not passed automatically).

Comment: you said you are submitting the form using submit button.

Comment: OP said that, yes ... But your code prevents the form being submitted. The default action of submit event is, well ... submit the form, not refreshing the page.

Comment: you need to make API call using ajax to submit the form.